# database insert returning -1

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my database as follows. I added the database and when I insert it returns -1. Is there something missing here.

**EDIT:**

```
public static final String DETAILS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
  + DETAILS_TABLE
  + "("
  +  DATABASE_KEY
  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
  + DATABASE_ENT1
  + " INT, "
  + DATABASE_ ENT2
  + " INT, "
  + DATABASE_ ENT3
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT4
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT5
  + " REAL, "
  + DATABASE_ENT
  + " REAL, "
  + DATABASE_ENT7
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT7
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT8
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT9
  + " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT10
  +  " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT11
  +  " TEXT, "
  + DATABASE_ENT12
  +  " TEXT "
  + ")";

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DATABASE_ENT1, ent1);
values.put(DATABASE_ENT2, ent2);
values.put(DATABASE_ENT3, ent3);

rowId = db.insert(DETAILS_TABLE_CREATE, null,
                values);
```

ERROR:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the `insert()` function must be the table name.
In this case, this would be `DETAILS_TABLE`.

(Use `insertOrThrow` to get a useful error message.)

Answer (score 3):

You're inserting a creation of a table. That is absolutely wrong.

Execute a raw query instead:

```
db.rawQuery(DETAILS_TABLE_CREATE, null);
```

Comment: I am executing when I app starts as db.execSQL(DatabaseConstants.TIMERESTRICTION_TABLE_CREATE);  and this creates the table but then I am using   ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); and adding values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I used the entire table create when I just had to add the table name. Did not see that. 
Thanks.